# Need help adjusting the grid size based on user input

Tags: javascript, function, loops, button, grid

Need help!

simply put I am creating a grid that is x * x. the "x" variable is going to be whatever the user inputs.

Where I am struggling is I need be able to click a button and have a prompt widow come up, collect the number the user enters, and then use that number as an argument for a function I created to build the grid.

As you can probably tell by my question, I am fairly new to coding. So the simpler the solution the better for me to understand.

Thanks a ton!

```
const div = document.querySelector('#container')
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.button-clear');
const resizeButton = document.querySelector('.button-resize')

createGrid = gridNumber => {
  if (gridNumber === undefined) {
    gridNumber = 16;
  } else gridNumber = gridNumber;

  let gridSize = gridNumber * gridNumber;
  for (i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    let squares = document.createElement('div');
    squares.classList.add('squares');
    div.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${gridNumber}, 1fr)`;
    div.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${gridNumber}, 1fr)`;
    div.appendChild(squares);
  }

  let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.squares');
  boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  }));
}

resetGrid = () => {
  
  let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.squares');
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  })
}

createGrid();

clearButton.addEventListener('click', resetGrid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `prompt` for the value and call the function again. Check for `undefined` in case user didn't enter anything.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#container')
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.button-clear');
const resizeButton = document.querySelector('.button-resize')

createGrid = gridNumber => {
  if (gridNumber === undefined) {
    gridNumber = 16;
  } else gridNumber = gridNumber;

  let gridSize = gridNumber * gridNumber;
  for (i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    let squares = document.createElement('div');
    squares.classList.add('squares');
    div.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${gridNumber}, 1fr)`;
    div.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${gridNumber}, 1fr)`;
    div.appendChild(squares);
  }

  let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.squares');
  boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  }));
}

resetGrid = () => {

  let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.squares');
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  })
}

createGrid(4);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', resetGrid);
resizeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var value = prompt("enter size: ", 16);
  if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
    return
  }
  createGrid(value)
});
```

```css
.squares {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>

<button class="button-clear">clear</button>
<button class="button-resize">resize</button>
```